# Why do we need a user-provided constructor for a const object?

Tags: c++

The rules of the language says the definition of a `const`, user-defined class needs to either be value-initialized or have a user-provided default-constructor.

```c++
const struct X { int v; } x;
```

If you don't give it one then you won't ever be able to give `v` a value since it cannot be mutated. But how would we benefit from a user-provided constructor like this:

```c++
const struct X { X() {} int v; } x;
```

This will still default-construct `v` which will keep it uninitialized. Why do we need this constructor for it to compile when there's no benefit over not having one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, the compiler can tell, from just the class definition (not the definition of any members) that the variable won't be initialised. The class definition must be available in order to define the variable, so it's simple to state a rule to say that says the program is ill-formed if a `const` variable is left uninitialised in that case.

In the second, it would need the definition of the user-declared constructor to determine whether or not it's initialised. That's not necessarily available when the compiler is dealing with the variable definition, so in general it can't check whether or not the constructor initialises everything; the constructor definition isn't necessarily available. As is often the case, a diagnosis isn't required even in those cases like this, where the constructor's definition is available and the compiler could figure it out.